# I am studing nasm.(paul carter) what i'm wrong?

Tags: assembly, mingw, nasm

I'm studing nasm(paul carter's books - PC Assembly Language)

```
first.asm
1 ; file: first.asm
2 ; First assembly program. This program asks for two integers as
3 ; input and prints out their sum.
4 ;
5 ; To create executable using djgpp:
6 ; nasm -f coff first.asm
7 ; gcc -o first first.o driver.c asm_io.o
```

book have me work this way.

but It's not working.

```
C:\temp>gcc -o first first.o driver.c asm_io.o
c:/win-builds64/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64
-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `first.o' is incompatible w
ith i386:x86-64 output
c:/win-builds64/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64
-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `asm_io.o' is incompatible
with i386:x86-64 output
first.o:first.asm:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `print_string'
first.o:first.asm:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `read_int'
c:/win-builds64/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64
-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.o: bad reloc address 0x10 in section `.text'
c:/win-builds64/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64
-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

this is error code.

I think one of two problems.

1. this book requests 34bits computer. but my computer is 64bits.
2. asm_io.o is wrong code.

please help me.

sorry, I can't speak english well.

Comment: Try using the `-m32` flag with `gcc`, or download a version of `gcc` that targets i386.

Answer (score 0):

You need [Carter's Example Code for Cygwin and Mingw32](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/cygwin-ex.zip). For your first program you need out of these:

```
cdecl.h
driver.c
first.asm
asm_io.inc
asm_io.o
```

Build `first.exe` with

```
nasm.exe -fwin32 first.asm
gcc.exe -m32 -o first.exe asm_io.o driver.c first.obj
```